How to keep alive web socket connection in background app?
How do I keep the web socket connection active even though it is in the background of the application?
Even though I am outside the application, I still want to receive messages sent by the web socket and update my database based on the messages received.
Initially I used work manager, is this a good enough solution?

You can use a background service, but maintaining a websocket connection over an extended period of time accumulates a significant drain on the battery. Also, there is no guarantee that the service will not be closed unexpectedly by a restrictive battery saver. The solution intended by Google is to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, but keep in mind that that routes all messages through Google's infrastructure.

@Leviathan is absolutely right

Foreground service.
